# Powershell run as administrator from execute path

Tags: powershell, parameters

I'm using a 3rd party monitoring service to restart services when they go down on various boxes.  The 3rd party agent allows me to kick off an external program to do what I need.  In this instance I've chosen powershell, and have a script that works fine.  The problem is, when the 3rd party kicks off the script, it's always running it under the user Contoso\SYSTEM, so it can't do what it needs due to permissions.  How can I force it to run under a different user?  It calls the script by doing the following:

```
 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -Command "C:\Scripts\test.ps1"
```

I can't figure out how to specify a different user in that line. Can anyone be of assistance?

Comment: Run the service as a user, not as a system.

Comment: A service can only run progeams as the same user that runs the service. To change the credentials of the user that runs the service, go Control Panel - Administrative tools - Services - find service - Properties - Logon as, then put credentials of some user that's assigned enough privileges to both monitor the system(s) and run the script, and save the settings.

Comment: perfect, that solved it, thank you